# Google API to get address corresponding to Latitude and Longitude in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am trying to get address corresponding to latitude and longitude using Google API only in C#.

I had already it working in JavaScript with jQuery. I now have to write code in C#. Could someone please let me know the equivalent C# API?

Comment: I removed the code block since it doesn't use an API, it just loaded jQuery. You should add the actual JavaScript  you use to get addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to do reverse geocoding. If you are using .net or mono, you should be use this library to easily accomplish this task: https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net

Answer (score 2):

This is called *reverse geocoding*, and if you really need to do it server-side, you just have to call the Google Maps API like this :

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false
```

This produces a result formatted in json.
Just read it in C# or VB.NET and look at the property `formatted_address`.

Please note **NOT** to add space between latitude and longitude, before or after the comma.

**Pay attention to *limitation* and *licence***

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#Limits), there is a request limit by 24hours peridod, depending of the licence you get.

Also remember :

> The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12).